# Fail to upload multiple objects with boto3 to google storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, boto3, boto

Pasting my code snippet below:

```py
args.tenant = "test-conversenow"
    try:
        print("Uploading models & sdk to spaces bucket...")
        gcs.meta.client.upload_file(core_dep, args.tenant, 'core/' + model_version)
        gcs.meta.client.upload_file(nlu_dep, args.tenant, 'nlu/' + model_version)
        gcs.meta.client.upload_file(sdk_dep, args.tenant, 'sdk/' + model_version)
        gcs.meta.client.upload_file(data_dep, args.tenant, 'data/' + model_version)
        print("Uploading done to bucket")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error uploading to bucket: ", err)
```

The error that I get is

> Error uploading to bucket:  Failed to upload
>   deployment/nlu/0.0.1.tar.gz to test-conversenow/nlu/0.0.1.tar.gz: An
>   error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the
>   CreateMultipartUpload operation: Invalid argument.

The first object is created and then my program fails when it tries to upload second object **nlu/0.0.1.tar.gz**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using s3transfer. Below is the code snippet.

```py
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
from s3transfer import TransferConfig, S3Transfer


myconfig = TransferConfig(
        multipart_threshold=9999999999999999,
        max_concurrency=10,
        num_download_attempts=10,
    )

client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
                      region_name=REGION_NAME,
                      endpoint_url=ENDPOINT_URL,
                      aws_access_key_id=CLIENT_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=CLIENT_SECRET,
                      config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
transfer = S3Transfer(client, myconfig)

try:
    print("Uploading models & sdk to spaces bucket...")
    transfer.upload_file(core_dep, args.tenant, 'core/' + model_version)
    transfer.upload_file(nlu_dep, args.tenant, 'nlu/' + model_version)
    transfer.upload_file(data_dep, args.tenant, 'data/' + model_version)
    transfer.upload_file(sdk_dep, args.tenant, 'sdk/' + model_version)
    print("Uploading done to bucket")
except Exception as err:
    print("Error uploading to bucket: ", err)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this in my recent sample work, below is the code;

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.9.203'



import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3') # s3 object to upload.
local_file_path = local_folder_path + "\\"+ file_name_to_upload # local_file_path = D:\Boto3Sample\sample.txt
s3.meta.client.upload_file(local_file_path, "s3BucketName", file_name_to_upload) # upload_file("D:\Boto3Sample\sample.txt", "s3BucketName", "sample.txt")
```

From your error message, it looks like, the value of Key(As per the docs, "The name of the key to upload to" 3rd parameter) has some issue when it is uploading to storage.

Comment: But it should fail for the first object as well. The first object is created on google cloud storage.